# Ubuntu 17.04 doesn't recognize my Nvidia Geforce 720M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.04

Recently, Ubuntu 17.04 doesn't recognize the secondary graphic card installed on my laptop by manufacturer. The graphic card model is Nvidia Geforce 720M.

Here is the output of commands I ran to diagnose the problem:

```
$ lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GeForce GT 720M
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_340
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
$ sudo nvidia-detector
none
$ nvidia-settings
ERROR: Unable to find display on any available system
$ optirun glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
[ 1142.796148] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[ 1142.796180] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
```

Comment: Are you running in a wayland environment?  Please add the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` to your question

Comment: Yes, I am. @CharlesGreen

Comment: Nvidia and Wayland don't play well together - logout of your Ubuntu session and start an xorg session of Ubuntu.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Interesting, they used to play well. I don't know what changes were made to my system, maybe an update or something.